# want help on regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a string like `'/whatever/whatver/whatever/v{int}'`
As the string shows, the string is compose of some prefix `'/whaterver'`,the string has prefix or not,either is ok and the last part is `/v{int}` 
I wrote a regular expression `(^[/][a-zA-Z]+)*/v[0-9]+`,  `(^[/][a-zA-Z]+)*` means the prefix can appear or not and `/v[0-9]+` to match the last part.

I guess the expression can fully match the string, but it doesn't.

Can any one help me ?

Comment: (^[/][a-zA-Z]+)/v[0-9]+ will not match multiple slashes

Comment: Which programming language are you using? And could you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Jack It's not about the programming language, it's about the regex standard.

Comment: @andrei different languages support different parts of the regex "standard". Stis becomes significant when suggestions are to be made. Even thr regex tag states a language tag should always be provided.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan, which regex standard? Each regex question needs an additional language tag, [see the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: given the regex tag is used, I don't think the title could get any less descriptive. We want descriptive titles on this site.

Comment: I'm using Java  @Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why the negation of `/` character?

Second, I can see you can have multiple prefixes, so you have to check also the multiple cardinality of prefixes (see the `*` wildcard I added).

This expression `([/][a-zA-Z]+)*/v[0-9]+` matches your input and also matches input with no prefix.

**EDIT**

In case you want to keep the beginning-of-line marker (even though it's redundant if you want an exact match), you need to exclude it form the repetitive block (marked with `*` wildcard), because you don't want the engine to look for new line beginnings in each prefix.

```
^([/][a-zA-Z]+)*/v[0-9]+
```

Comment: The ^ is not inside [], so it's not a negation, it's "at the beginning of the line".

Comment: @Andrei Nicusan  I want the exact match since I do not want many slashes at the begining like '///whatever/whatever/.../v{int}'. I paste the regular expression in http://regexpal.com/ and it can match the string above.     Resolved my problem. thanks

Comment: It's regexpal that I usually utilize, also.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "/whatever/whatver/whatever/v1654" | grep -E '^/?([a-zA-Z]+/)+v[0-9]+$'
/whatever/whatver/whatever/v1654
```